# How to call a module variable from a module not named config.py

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I have three files: `config.py`, `something_else.py` and `run_this_script.py`.
`config.py` and `something_else.py` each have a variable I need to call from within `run_this_script.py`.

This works from within `run_this_script.py`:

```py
import config 
print(config.variable)
```

This does not work from within `run_this_script.py`:

```py
import anything_else 
print(anything_else.variable)
```

The file name config somehow allows me to call variables from it but modules with any other name will not allow me to call their variables. How can I call a variable from another module named `anything_else.py`?

Comment: Patch your import statement in `run_this_script.py` with new module name.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify that your suggestion is part of whats not working for me

Comment: It's nonsense, I'm sure that this issue can't be caused by renaming file. Maybe file gets somehow locked on os level?

Comment: restarting the kernel in VS Code seems to have fixed the probem